# Unused Parameters

Tags: parameters, return, return-value

I am familiar with the concept of unused parameters in functions, declared with an underscore to improve readability. However, I don't understand, why the two functions below spit out different results, if the first parameter is never used. Am I missing a basic rule of computer science. Looking forward to a good answer and hope this doesn't consume a lot of your time?

```
function vowel2index(str) {
return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, (i) => i + 1)
}
```

### Returns: 'thi1s i1s my stri1ng'

```
function vowel2index(str) {
return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, (_, i) => i + 1)
}
```

### Returns: 'th3s 6s my str15ng' (which would be the expected answer)

cheers

Comment: Because replacer function receives more than one parameter and order matters: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace

Comment: didnt the replace function get the regex as the first parameter? Why does the order of a totally new function matter? Isn't the arrow function already the second parameter? I'm sorry, I just dont get it